# Perl one-liner to herding a group of sequences to be processed in a block

Tags: perl

How Perl one-liner for herding a group of sequences, out of its superset group, to be processed in a block of codes

The task fail done:

```
$ for i in {1..9} ;{ echo $i ;} |perl -pe 'my $s; if (/3/) {  while(1) { $s .= $_; print $s; last if (/7/) }  } '
```

to use Perl `-pe` option do output of string lines of:

```
1
2
3
4567
8
9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
for i in `seq 9` ; do echo $i; done | \
    perl -lne 'if ($_ == 3 .. $_ == 7) { push @a, $_; print @a if $_ == 7; next; } print;'
1
2
34567
8
9
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: please point me ebook or PDF on reference of / /../ / syntax or command (just like sed's / /,/ / ?

Comment: @itilmemekcantik: This is the Perl range, or flip-flop operator. See: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators , https://stackoverflow.com/q/26936654/967621